# Concatenating two Pandas columns based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two columns and I'm trying to make a new one depending if one has a null value or not. I have the following example and I´m trying to use the np.where() function but it doesn´t seems to work.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# DF 1
a = pd.DataFrame([1,'nan',2],columns=['a1'])
# DF 2
b = pd.DataFrame(['hola','hola','hola'],columns=['b1']) 
# New Column
b['b2'] = np.where(a['a1'].astype(str) != 'nan', b['b1'] + a['a1'].astype(str))
```

The result for the new column 'b2' should be:

```
hola1  
hola 
hola2
```

The `np.where` function also doesn´t has like an else option so I don´t know how to include that. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I added a comparative timing for some solutions proposed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "synchronize" `a` and `b` dataframes to make pairwise comparisons (possibly with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)):

```
b['b2'] = pd.concat([a.replace({'nan': ''}), b], axis=1).apply(lambda x:x['b1'] + str(x['a1']), axis=1)
print(b)
```

---

```
     b1     b2
0  hola  hola1
1  hola   hola
2  hola  hola2
```

Answer (score 0):

@RomanPerekhrest's solution is fine and you should upvote it. There is a vectorial solution if you like to try.

```py
df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)

df["b2"] = df["b1"] + df["a1"].astype("str")\
    .str.replace("nan", "")
```

which returns

```bash
    a1    b1     b2
0    1  hola  hola1
1  nan  hola   hola
2    2  hola  hola2
```

In case you really want to use `np.where` you can try

```py
df["b3"] = np.where(
    df['a1'].eq('nan'),
    df['b1'],
    df['b1'] + df['a1'].astype(str))
```

which leads to

```bash
    a1    b1     b2     b3
0    1  hola  hola1  hola1
1  nan  hola   hola   hola
2    2  hola  hola2  hola2
```

**EDIT - Timing**

Here a small experiment when we assume a, and b have 30.000 rows.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
n = 10_000
a = pd.DataFrame([1,'nan',2],columns=['a1'])
# DF 2
b = pd.DataFrame(['hola','hola','hola'],columns=['b1'])
a = pd.concat([a for i in range(n)],
             ignore_index=True)
b = pd.concat([b for i in range(n)],
             ignore_index=True)

a_bk = a.copy()
b_bk = b.copy()
```

## @RomanPerekhrest's solution

```py
%%timeit -n 10 -r 3
a = a_bk.copy()
b = b_bk.copy()
b['b2'] = pd.concat(
    [a.replace({'nan': ''}), 
     b],
    axis=1)\
    .apply(lambda x:x['b1'] + str(x['a1']), axis=1)
```

```bash
305 ms ± 17.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
```

## Vectorial solution

```py
%%timeit -n 10 -r 3
a = a_bk.copy()
b = b_bk.copy()
df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)

df["b2"] = df["b1"] + df["a1"].astype("str")\
    .str.replace("nan", "")
```

```bash
33.6 ms ± 4.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
```

## Conclusion

Vectorial solution is 9x faster than using an apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution using list comprehension:

```
b['b2'] = [str(j) if i=='nan' else str(j) + str(i) for i, j in zip(a.a1,b.b1) ]

print(b)

     b1     b2
0  hola  hola1
1  hola   hola
2  hola  hola2
```

I have used zip to loop both columns together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple string concatenation:

```
>>> b['b1'] + a['a1'].astype(str).replace('nan', '')

0    hola1
1     hola
2    hola2
dtype: object
```